# Вставка времени в поле  ?

Tags: php, html, form, время

Доброго времени суток, столкнулся с такой проблемой, есть html форма , в ней поля название, радиус и самое главное Время начала и конца.
так выглядят мои поля:
    < input type="text" name="begintime" >
проблема в том что мне надо чтобы пользователь при нажатие на поле формы набирал время так как как мне это надо в формате ЧЧ:ММ:СС , да можно конечно потом проверять то что он набрал на корректность, но если есть способ вызова какого-нибудь циферблата на котором ты просто выбираешь время или как в андройде настройку часов. Подскажите кто что знает и покажите по возможности.

Comment: Проверять понадобиться в любом случае, огорчу Вас. Пользователь выберет дату, а потом введёт что-нибудь ненормальное, либо сразу введёт что-нибудь ненормальное =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Погуглите по запросу "jquery input time" и будет очень много плагинчиков для вас.
От себя могу посоветовать вот [этот](http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/) плагин.

Answer (score 3):

В html5 есть новый тип тега input time

```
<input type="time" name="time" />
```

отображает специальное поле для ввода времени, но поддержка еще очень слабая.

Так что плагины jQeury в вашем случае выход, например, [ClockPick](http://www.jnathanson.com/index.cfm?page=jquery/clockpick/ClockPick) или самому скрипт написать.

Comment: ага, ff в моём линухе не знает ничего об этом type="time", а хром показал, как надо

Comment: да, в ответе же и написано, что поддержка слабая http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime